# jquery serialize() method returns only __VIEWSTATE and __VIEWSTATEGENERATOR

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, serialization

I am trying to serialize form elements in my asp.net(aspx) page using jquery but I can only get two parameters __VIEWSTATE and __VIEWSTATEGENERATOR. I can not get input fields and other form controls. I have searched but failed to fix it. Could you please say me where I am doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="JqueryLearning.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="scripts/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" />
            <input id="Text1" type="text" value="123" />
            <input id="Hidden1" type="hidden" value="test"/>
            <div id="div1">
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <script>
        $("#Button1").click(function () {
            var data = $("#form1").serialize();
            $("#div1").text(data);
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is serialized data:

```
__VIEWSTATE=eFPd1%2Bmmj0NP%2F%2BQpnQb0QJAGu5msYSVHERz6tGgxWTKxoqlFiTVTWPRaa2YN1cmxW%2FwYHxB59GzNpAOWyTwPV6omrNKCzlKRL3F874WB1Hg%3D&__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR=B6E7D48B
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that all controls to be serialized must have a name .

> Note: Only "successful controls" are serialized to the string. No
>   submit button value is serialized since the form was not submitted
>   using a button. For a form element's value to be included in the
>   serialized string, the element must have a name attribute. Values from
>   checkboxes and radio buttons (inputs of type "radio" or "checkbox")
>   are included only if they are checked. Data from file select elements
>   is not serialized.